# Set featured link not showing

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, media

I created my own custom wordpress theme now i am able to add media to my site but the "set featured" link does not show, please i need some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your theme needs to support Post Thumbnails to have the featured image meta box...
Add this to your functions.php file:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails